# A diophantine equation

Tags: nt.number-theory

A few days ago I saw a question about the diophantine equation $p^2+p+1=q^\alpha$ in 
[What is prime power of this equation of p?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/206931/what-is-prime-power-of-this-equation-of-p)

and later in

[A Diophantine equation with prime powers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/207024/a-diophantine-equation-with-prime-powers)

I want the similar results about the following diophantine equation $p^2-p+1=q^\alpha$ and $p^2-p+1=3q^\alpha$, where $p$ and $q$ are prime numbers.

Of course we know that $19^2-19+1=7^3$, but is there any answer for these equations? In fact in very special cases we see $\alpha=1$ and so is there only finite answers where $\alpha=1$?

As I checked for p<400000 only there exists one solution as above.
Any comments and hints are highly appreciated.

Comment: You have both $a$ and $\alpha$, and may want to fix it. Also, have your read the comments to Geoff Robinson's answer here: http://mathoverflow.net/a/206941/16537?

Comment: The post http://mathoverflow.net/questions/207024/a-diophantine-equation-with-prime-powers refers to a paper of Nagell in which the equations $x^2+x+1=y^n$ and $x^2+x+1=3 y^n$ for $n \ge 3$. You want to take $x=-p$, $y=q$, $n=\alpha$ which reduces you to the case where $\alpha=1$ or $2$.

Comment: Nowadays such equations are treated using the primitive divisor theorem of Bilu, Hanrot and Voutier. See for example page 420 of "Number Theory: Volume I: Tools and Diophantine Equations" by Henri Cohen.

Comment: Thank you very much for the useful comments. For the first equation when $n=3^b$, can we discuss about the solutions?

Comment: The equation $x^2+x+1=y^3$ is an elliptic curve with trivial Mordell--Weil group. It has no integral points.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers and for the comments.

Comment: @Siksek, your last comment is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Nagell proved in 1921 that the equations $$p^2\pm p+1=q^\alpha$$ and $$p^2\pm p+1=3q^\alpha$$ have no nontrivial integral solutions for odd $\alpha$ except possibly for the first equation when $\alpha=3^k$ for some positive integer $k$.

The equation $p^2\pm p+1=q^2$ has no nontrivial integer solutions, while the equation $p^2\pm p+1=q^3$ have no nontrivial integer solutions except $q^\alpha=7^3=343$, giving $p=18$ (not prime) to $$p^2+p+1=q^3$$ and $p=19$ (prime) to $$p^2-p+1=q^3$$

Hence $p^2\pm p+1=3q^2$ for some prime power $q$.